# How to pass value from state as a parameter to function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I've been trying to figure out how can I pass value from state (personId) to function (fetchPersonInfo) as a parameter, but nothing that I've tried has yet to work. So I thought to come ask your help with this.

```
class Page extends Component {

    state = {
        personId: '',
    }

    componentDidUpdate = () => {
        if(this.props.results.length > 0 && this.state.personId !== this.props.results[0].results[0].id){
            if(this.props.results[0].results[0].media_type === 'person'){
                this.setState({personId: this.props.results[0].results[0].id});
                this.personInfo(personId);
            }
        }
    }

    personInfo = (personId) => {
        if(this.state.personId.length > 0){
            this.props.fetchPersonInfo(personId);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you not just passing `this.state.personId` to `personInfo` in the first place?

Comment: @MarkC. Hey, if you mean like this "personInfo = (this.state.personId) => {" it gives some kind of "formatting" error with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

React `setState` is asynchronous, you cannot call `personInfo()` in a sync way as you're doing

```
this.setState({personId: this.props.results[0].results[0].id});
this.personInfo(personId);
```

assuming the rest of the code is fine, change the above code to

```
this.setState({personId: this.props.results[0].results[0].id}, this.personInfo);
```

and remove personId parameter from the function

```
personInfo = () => {
    if(this.state.personId){
      this.props.fetchPersonInfo(this.state.personId);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is here:

```
this.setState({personId: this.props.results[0].results[0].id});
this.personInfo(personId);
```

Call the persionInfo in this way: `this.personInfo(this.props.results[0].results[0].id)`

Or:

```
this.props.fetchPersonInfo(this.state.personId);
```